# Gradle unable to find transitive dependency when transitive dependency has version as a variable

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies, maven-repository

build.gradle has the following dependencies -

```
dependencies {
    compile("com.rhuldip.artifactId:com.rhuldip.mainDependency:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
}
```

In my maven repository, I have the following files at location REPO_URL/com/rhuldip/artifactId/com.rhuldip.mainDependency/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

1. maven-metadata.XML
2. com.rhuldip.mainDependency-1.0.0.pom
3. com.rhuldip.mainDependency-1.0.0.jar

The file *com.rhuldip.mainDependency-1.0.0.pom* contains transitive dependency and a variable like this -

```
<properties>
    <myapp.version>${revision}</myapp.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rhuldip.myapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>transitiveDependeny</artifactId>
            <version>${myapp.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

But I am getting this error -

```
***
01:08:40    > Could not resolve com.rhuldip.artifactId:com.rhuldip.mainDependency:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
01:08:40       > Could not parse POM REPO-URL/com/rhuldip/artifactId/com.rhuldip.mainDependency/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/com.rhuldip.mainDependency-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
01:08:40          > Could not find com.rhuldip.myapp:transitiveDependeny:${revision}.
```

I am using gradle ***4.10.2*** version.
I tried sending a revision variable like this but still getting the same error

```
ext {
    revision: '1.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have:

```bash
Gradle Project
│
└── build.gradle
    └── dependencies
        └── com.rhuldip.artifactId:com.rhuldip.mainDependency:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
            └── Maven Repository
                ├── com.rhuldip.mainDependency-1.0.0.pom
                │   └── transitiveDependeny with ${revision} as version
                └── com.rhuldip.mainDependency-1.0.0.jar
```

You need to explicitly define the `revision` property in your Gradle build script so that it can be properly resolved when fetching the transitive dependency.
But: [Gradle 4.10.2](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/release-notes.html) (2018!) does not automatically pass properties defined in the [`ext` block](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:extra_properties) to the Maven POM resolver. You can try instead defining this property at the top level of your build script.

A [resolution strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) to substitute the variable in the transitive dependency version could help... even in 4.10.2.
Use the `ResolutionStrategy` in your `build.gradle` file to dynamically replace the version of the transitive dependency.
Implement the strategy to replace the dynamic version (`${revision}`) with a specific version for `transitiveDependeny`.

Your `build.gradle` file would be:

```
ext {
    myappVersion = '1.1.0-SNAPSHOT' // Define the specific version you want to use
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.rhuldip.myapp' && details.requested.name == 'transitiveDependeny') {
            if (details.requested.version == '${revision}') {
                details.useVersion myappVersion
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("com.rhuldip.artifactId:com.rhuldip.mainDependency:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
}
```

That configuration in your `build.gradle` tells Gradle to replace the `${revision}` placeholder in the version of `transitiveDependeny` with the specific version `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

---

As an alternative workaround, you can explicitly declare the transitive dependency in your `build.gradle` file with the correct version. That way, Gradle will not rely on the POM file to resolve the version. And modify your `build.gradle` to include the transitive dependency with a specific version.

```
dependencies {
    compile("com.rhuldip.artifactId:com.rhuldip.mainDependency:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
    // Explicitly specify the version for the transitive dependency
    compile("com.rhuldip.myapp:transitiveDependeny:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT")
}
```

That approach essentially bypasses the issue by not relying on the Maven POM file to resolve the dynamic version of `transitiveDependeny`. Instead, you are directly specifying the dependency and its version in your Gradle project.

---

> Still getting the same error.
>
> Also, The dependency is in a remote maven repository and `com.rhuldip.artifactId:com.rhuldip.mainDependency` has a transitive dependency with `artifactId` `com.rhuldip.myapp` and name as `transitiveDependency`.
> The dependency is declared in `com.rhuldip.artifactId:com.rhuldip.mainDependency-1.0.0.pom`, but the actual location of the transitive dependency is at `REO_URL/com/rhuldip/myapp`.

So the transitive dependency is hosted in a *remote* Maven repository. That means the repository configuration in your Gradle project must correctly point to this remote repository.

And the problem is that the version of the transitive dependency is specified as a variable (`${revision}`) in the POM file of `com.rhuldip.artifactId:com.rhuldip.mainDependency`.

Make sure your `build.gradle` includes the remote Maven repository where `com.rhuldip.myapp` is located:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'REPO_URL' // Replace with the actual URL of your remote Maven repository
    }
    // Include other necessary repositories, like mavenCentral, if needed
}
```

Since the resolution strategy to replace the `${revision}` placeholder does not work as expected, try and explicitly declare the transitive dependency with a fixed version, as previously mentioned. That is a more direct approach and can sometimes bypass issues with variable resolution in POM files.

Define the `revision` variable in a `gradle.properties` file, which might be more effective in some setups.

Your `build.gradle` would be:

```
dependencies {
    compile("com.rhuldip.artifactId:com.rhuldip.mainDependency:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
    // Explicitly define the transitive dependency
    compile("com.rhuldip.myapp:transitiveDependency:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT")
}
```

And the `gradle.properties` file:

```
revision=1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

But make sure the version `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` of `com.rhuldip.myapp:transitiveDependency` is indeed available in the remote repository. If it is not, replace this with the correct available version.

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: Also, The dependency is in a remote maven repository and com.rhuldip.artifactId:com.rhuldip.mainDependency has a transitive dependency with artifactId com.rhuldip.myapp and name as transitiveDependeny. The dependency is declared in com.rhuldip.artifactId:com.rhuldip.mainDependency-1.0.0.pom but the actual location of the transitive dependency is at REO_URL/com/rhuldip/myapp.

Comment: @RAHULDEEP I have edited the answer to address your comment. I suppose you cannot upgrade Gradle, but I wonder if the resolution strategy to replace the `${revision}` placeholder would have worked with a more recent version of Gradle.

Comment: Yes, I won't be able to upgrade my gradle. 

When explicitly using the version for transitive dependency, the transitive dependency is getting downloaded(seen by using the -d command) but still getting the same error. 

Using gradle.properties file is also not working.

Comment: @RAHULDEEP I suppose a `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies` would not help? Since you mentioned using the -d command, is there any clue in the detailed logs?